# "random" kernel crash after running for minutes.... HEP!? -- [same question posted on Khronos]

Tags: opencl

I have a thoroughly complex kernel processing audio input data. It will run for a couple of minutes, 60 times a second, and then hang. That's on the GPU; on the CPU it will run for hours. The input data are constantly changing, but each variable is always within proscribed ranges. I have inserted test code before uploading the inputs to the kernel each frame; in this test code, I can force these inputs to be well below their valid input range, but it still will eventually crash. (Say the valid range for a particular input is 0->400; I can force it to 0->1 and it will STILL eventually crash. I can force it to be below 0.1 and it will still ultimately bite the dust.) However, if I force the input variables to zero, the GPU will happily dance for hours. Of course, that input-free dance is not so particularly interesting.

I'm at a loss so far, though I have clues. I can make it crash much faster than 2 minutes if an input variable is high in its approved range. I can make it crash in less then 10 seconds under the right circumstances. BUT, I can't seem to _back_off_of_ those certain circumstances such that they go away. As said above, I can force the input vars into ridiculously small portions of their valid range, and the kernel (let's call him Harlan Sanders) will eventually go belly-up. BUT, if they're forced to *actual* zero, no problems puppy, we can run all day long.

To repeat, I'm a bit at a loss - although I have things that look like clues, I have not yet figured out what they are hinting at, though I've been trying for a few days. Frankly, I do not expect to find a real solution by asking here; whenever I stumble over a problem in opencl it seems that my fate is to be the first to articulate that particular problem. I guess this is part of the fun of being in on a technology during its infancy!!!!!!!!!! BUT, I want to do some serious, sustainable work with this "baby" (or, maybe, "toddler").

Op details: MacBook Pro 2010, OS 10.6.8, nv 330M GPU, xcode 3.2.5, shorts, teeshirt.

bonus P.S. for those who've read this far, including a related question:
My laptop, soldier that it has proved to be, is not powerful enough for the next stage. I must sell some stocks/bonds and purchase a Mac Pro. I'm looking at the ATI 5870. So, PERHAPS my problem will simply go away when I compile the .cl for the ATI??? Maybe I have run into a bug in the nV implementation. Maybe my kernel is so complex that I'm running into undetected resource limits (it's 1300 lines of code). So, SINCE I run fine on the CPU, perhaps I'll have no bugs, or different bugs, on the ATI card???

Any thoughts?

Thanks, guys & dolls --
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Use "cl_" data types on the CPU side, because maybe you are not coping data the right way, or it is not being understood by the GPU. This could lead to GPU hangs on invalid pointers while handing the data.
You should also try -Werror, and read the error output. You can be doing smt wrong.

Without any code, we can only guess. But I haven't found any bug in the actual OpenCL NV or ATI implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I'll try to figure out how to pass -Werror in through xcode to the opencl compiler.  I'd love better error info than INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE on my enqueued read. I may also try cl_ data types; I'm currently just passing in a single struct full of floats, shorts and chars.

Comment: <continued; passed 5-minute edit limit>  Funny thing is, commenting out something like "T = 1.-T" in-kernel can fix it (inloaded params are normalized 0->1, so this should have no procedural effect.) Funny too that it'll run ~5400x b4 failing. Sorry; won't saddle you with 1300 lines, and core algorithms are sensitive material.  If I can pare it down, I shall!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you release all resources. Events returned by Enqueue functions must be released. This error sometimes occurs after accessing buffers out of range.

Comment: Thanks! I did think of that, but I'm passing in NULL where it would pass back events, I think, so they shouldn't need to be released?...  i.e. "err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, invars, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof( varholder ), &f, 0, NULL, NULL);"  and  " err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel( queue, kernel, 2, NULL, glbsz, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL );"  and "err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, outbuf, CL_TRUE, 0, obufsize, buf, 0, NULL, NULL );"